# Annotation like @depreciated

Tags: java, annotations

I'd like to implement an annotation for methods which will let me know where those annotated methods called, just like official @deprecated annotation.

How can I get the list of all calling methods for a given annotated method?

Comment: At compile time / in an IDE? You would need write your own tool if you really want that. Something like http://tools.android.com/tips/lint or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13563820/create-a-java-annotation-with-ide-contextual-behaviour

Comment: @zapl I want to track points where gcm.send is called, which must not be called from main thread.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Intellij/ Java - identify calls to annotated methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26213727/intellij-java-identify-calls-to-annotated-methods)

Answer (score 0):

I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/259140/scanning-java-annotations-at-runtime) may help you:

To find this annotated method (from [Arthur Ronald's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/259140/scanning-java-annotations-at-runtime/1415338#1415338)):

> use
>   [org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.html)
>
> API
>
> > A component provider that scans the classpath from a base package. It then applies exclude and include filters to the resulting classes
> >     to find candidates.
>
> ```
> ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider scanner =
> new ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider(<DO_YOU_WANT_TO_USE_DEFALT_FILTER>);
>
> scanner.addIncludeFilter(new AnnotationTypeFilter(<TYPE_YOUR_ANNOTATION_HERE>.class));
>
> for (BeanDefinition bd : scanner.findCandidateComponents(<TYPE_YOUR_BASE_PACKAGE_HERE>))
>     System.out.println(bd.getBeanClassName());
> ```

Or (from [Jonathan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/259140/scanning-java-annotations-at-runtime/3391773#3391773)):

> Google reflections:
>
> https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections
>
> Quick review:
>
> - Spring solution is the way to go if you're using Spring. Otherwise it's a big dependency.
> - Using ASM directly is a bit cumbersome.
> - Using Java Assist directly is clunky too.
> - Annovention is super lightweight and convenient. No maven integration yet.
> - Google reflections pulls in Google collections. Indexes everything and then is super fast.

**Update**: If want to calling methods for a given annotated method, you should use AOP (Aspect Oriented Programming) and add @ Around or @ Before, for example something like this (I don't check this code):

```
public class Foo {
  @YourAnnotation
  public int power(int x, int p) {
    return Math.pow(x, p);
  }
}

@Aspect
public class MethodLogger {
  @Around("execution(* *(..)) && @annotation(YourAnnotation)")
  public Object around(ProceedingJoinPoint point) {
    Logger.info(
      "call by method" + MethodSignature.class.cast(point.getSignature()).getMethod().getName()
    );
    Object result = point.proceed();
    return result;
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to find annotated methods but methods calling annotated methods.

Comment: I rellay appreciate your help but I want to do this at compile time like android lint does. Maybe my question wasn't clear enough.

Comment: unfortunately  finding method calls to an annotated method is not possible with structural search: https://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5451478

Comment: Do you try to search a plugin in  https://plugins.jetbrains.com/category/index?pr=idea&category_id=3 ? If its really need, you can try to create you own custom plugin unsing http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/getting_started.html